# JPA Get an entity by intermediate entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities named Student, Course, and StudentCourse as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String fullName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String courseName;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "student_course")
public class StudeCourse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer studentId;
    private Integer courseId;
    private String extraColumn;
}
```

**Restrictions:** There are a couple of restrictions

1. One student can have only one course or no course at all
2. An extra entity (StudentCourse) is required to hold the relation with primary key as studentId only
3. StudentCourse is required and hence cannot be skipped
4. Get Student with Course entity if there is one registered

**Help** required in some magical code to retrieve Course of Student if there is one assigned.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id; 
    private String fullName;

    // this is not correct code but just what I want
    @JoinEntity(entity=StudentCourse, column="courseId")
    private Course course;
}
```

Comment: So, what happens if you use that? What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

> `StudentCourse` is required and hence cannot be skipped

Ok, lets work with that.

> One student can have only one course or no course at all

Implies that there is a `@OneToOne` relationship between `Student` and `StudentCourse`.

---

With the given information, the following entity model will work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String full_name;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private StudentCourse studentCourse;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_course")
public class StudentCourse {
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    private Student student;

    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Course course;

    ...
}
```

A quick review:

1. `@OneToOne` on the `Student.studentCourse` field signifies that for every `Student`, there can be only one `StudentCourse`, and no more.
2. `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` on the `Student.studentCourse` field signifies that the value of the primary key column for `Student` should be used as the foreign key for the related entity, that is, `StudentCourse`.
3. `@OneToOne` on the `StudentCourse.student` field signifies that for every `StudentCourse`, there can be only one `Student`.
4. `@MapsId` on the `StudentCourse.student` field signifies that the primary key column for `StudentCourse` should be used as the join column for the association.

To check if a student has a course assigned, simply check if `student.getStudentCourse() != null` and then get the assigned course as `student.getStudentCourse().getCourse()`.